# Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin' | cannot install npm packages

Tags: npm, webpack

I work on a external project and get this error while "npm install".

```
patch-package 6.4.7
Applying patches...

**ERROR** Failed to apply patch for package webpack-publish-plugin at path
  
    node_modules/webpack-publish-plugin

  This error was caused because webpack-publish-plugin has changed since you
  made the patch file for it. This introduced conflicts with your patch,
  just like a merge conflict in Git when separate incompatible changes are
  made to the same piece of code.

  Maybe this means your patch file is no longer necessary, in which case
  hooray! Just delete it!

  Otherwise, you need to generate a new patch file.

  To generate a new one, just repeat the steps you made to generate the first
  one.

  i.e. manually make the appropriate file changes, then run 

    patch-package webpack-publish-plugin

  Info:
    Patch file: patches/webpack-publish-plugin+1.1.0.patch
    Patch was made for version: 1.1.0
    Installed version: 1.3.3

---
patch-package finished with 1 error(s).
```

Try to install manually.. but it failed again.

```
$ npm install patch-package

> cpu-features@0.0.8 install /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/cpu-features
> node buildcheck.js > buildcheck.gypi && node-gyp rebuild

  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_aarch64_linux_or_android.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_arm_linux_or_android.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_mips_linux_or_android.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_ppc_linux.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_x86_freebsd.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_x86_linux_or_android.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_x86_macos.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/impl_x86_windows.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/filesystem.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/stack_line_reader.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/cpu_features/deps/cpu_features/src/string_view.o
  LIBTOOL-STATIC Release/cpu_features.a
env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [Release/cpu_features.a] Error 127
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/penny/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/penny/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/bin/node" "/Users/penny/.nvm/versions/node/v12.22.9/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/cpu-features
gyp ERR! node -v v12.22.9
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN acorn-import-assertions@1.9.0 requires a peer of acorn@^8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN update-browserslist-db@1.0.11 requires a peer of browserslist@>= 4.21.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN noodle@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN noodle@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: cpu-features@0.0.8 (node_modules/cpu-features):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: cpu-features@0.0.8 install: `node buildcheck.js > buildcheck.gypi && node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ patch-package@6.5.1
added 7 packages from 4 contributors, updated 8 packages and audited 1250 packages in 10.119s

126 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 27 vulnerabilities (14 moderate, 11 high, 2 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

The NPM version of the project is v12.22.9. I already downgrade.

Run "npm run watch"

```
❯ npm run watch

> noodle@1.0.0 watch /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child
> npx webpack --watch

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/lib/rules/DescriptionDataMatcherRulePlugin'
Require stack:
- /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/plugin-webpack5.js
- /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/plugin.js
- /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/webpack/optiweb-webpack-loaders.js
- /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/webpack.config.js
- /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/plugin-webpack5.js:6:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/plugin-webpack5.js',
    '/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/plugin.js',
    '/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/webpack/optiweb-webpack-loaders.js',
    '/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/webpack.config.js',
    '/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/Users/penny/Workspace/wordpress/web/app/themes/oasis-child/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem? I only want to start scss in this project to get the files build.